# Уязвим ли данный код к sql Инъекции?

Tags: php, yii2

Во фреймворке есть `ActibeRecord`, у которого есть метод `where`. В нём можно передать условие как в виде строки, так и в виде массива ключ-значение. Если во втором случае фреймворк будет биндить переменные в запросе, то в первом случае неизвестно. Информации по данному вопросу не нашёл. Скажите, будет ли фреймворк как-то разбивать строки и биндить переменные или такой код, без самостоятиельного биндинга будет уязвим?

Пример:

```
public function getNumberMax(int $userId): int {
    $numberMax = User::find()
        ->select(['max(number)'])
        ->where('user_id=' . $userId)
        ->scalar();

    return (int)$numberMax;
}
```

Как его корректно написать в итоге? Или так тоже можно и он не будет подвержен инъекции?

Comment: Странный вопрос. "Если я буду тыкать вилкой себе в глаз, я ослепну или нет?"

Comment: Скажи, как можно "не найти информацию", если мне например гугль первой ссылкой по запросу yii инъекции выдаёт https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/security-best-practices/

Comment: хм....что же получается. если писать даже так `->where(['user_id' => $userId])` то фреймворк внутри себя не анализиует ключ-значение и не будет подготавливать выражение?

Comment: Где написано что не будет?

Comment: @Ипатьев не написано. но раз в статье пишется для исключения sql инъекции писать в таком виде `->where('status=:status', [':status' => $status])`, то встаёт логичный вопрос.

Comment: вот еще одна ссылка. в ней написано как работать с запросами: https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-query-builder/

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо. Буду учиться пользоваться поиском))